# jasper reports thowing huge error stack trace while filling an element with markup set to "HTML"

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am getting the below error when jasper reports is filling an element with markup set to "html". But the PDF is generated successfully as desired. This huge exception stack trace is filling up the disk space on the servers.

Here is the exception. Please help.

```
2013-10-03 00:42:45.383+0000 [http-thread-pool-8080(1)] ERROR j.e.s.s.c.s.e.server.logging
 [LogDomains.java:372] - UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for:
 javax.swing.JEditorPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,
 maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=,disabledTextColor=,editable=true,
 margin=,selectedTextColor=,selectionColor=,kit=,typeHandlers=]
2013-10-03 00:42:45.385+0000 [http-thread-pool-8080(1)] ERROR j.e.s.s.c.s.e.server.logging [LogDomains.java:372] - java.lang.Error
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:731)
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:130)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:761)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1013)
        at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(JTextComponent.java:348)
        at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.(JTextComponent.java:322)
        at javax.swing.JEditorPane.(JEditorPane.java:199)
        at javax.swing.JEditorPane.(JEditorPane.java:291)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JEditorPaneHtmlMarkupProcessor.convert(JEditorPaneHtmlMarkupProcessor.java:80)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.processMarkupText(JRFillTextElement.java:847)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:455)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:406)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.FillListContents.evaluateContents(FillListContents.java:79)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.prepare(VerticalFillList.java:101)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:129)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:393)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterSamePage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1069)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1032)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:296)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:135)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:540)
        at edu.apollogrp.lp.format.converters.jasper.SyllabusReportJasper.constructReport(SyllabusReportJasper.java:89)
        at edu.apollogrp.lp.format.converters.jasper.SyllabusReportJasper.generateReport(SyllabusReportJasper.java:42)
        at edu.apollogrp.lp.format.converters.pdf.impl.SyllabusFormatter.populateReport(SyllabusFormatter.java:306)
        at edu.apollogrp.lp.format.converters.pdf.impl.SyllabusFormatter.convert(SyllabusFormatter.java:251)
        at edu.apollogrp.lp.format.converters.pdf.impl.SyllabusFormatter$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b406e371.invoke()
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at edu.apollogrp.lp.format.converters.pdf.impl.SyllabusFormatter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$134484fa.convert()
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor415.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at edu.apollogrp.instrumentation.filter.InstrumentationServletFilter.doFilter(InstrumentationServletFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at edu.apollogrp.security.arms.filter.ArmsClassroomFilter.doFilter(ArmsClassroomFilter.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.P
2013-10-03 00:42:45.387+0000 [http-thread-pool-8080(1)] ERROR j.e.s.s.c.s.e.server.logging [LogDomains.java:372] - rocessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: I read server and ui class related issues. Maybe the server is not properly configured for headless use?

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml*?

Comment: Here I am pasting the jrxml -

Comment: I am not able to post the complete jrxml.. its too long.. is there a way to upload a the jrxml ?